# Simple Harmonic Question regarding acceleration

Tags: calculus, physics

I would just like to clear something up in regards to acceleration in SHM.

When a question asks to find ***maximum acceleration***, why do the solutions require you to use the absolute value of acceleration to find the result?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a simple harmonic motion then the particle position is given by

$$x(t) = A \cos(\omega t + \theta_0),$$

where $\omega$ is the angular frequency, $\theta_0$ is the initial angle and $A >0$ is the motion's amplitude.

*The amplitude always multiplies the cosine/sine function and represents the maximum value of the physical entity*.

Therefore, in order to find the farthest position you need to compute the largest $|x|$, which is $A$. The same idea applies to $a(t) = d^2 x/dt^2$. In this case

$$a(t) = -A\omega^2 \cos(\omega t + \theta_0)$$

and the maximum acceleration is $a_{\text{max}} = A\omega^2$.

Comment: OH right! So the maximum acceleration correlates to the amplitude of the function, which of course is an absolute value?

Also, when you're just given the relation: $a=-n^2*x$ why is the maximum acceleration found using $|-n^2*x|$?

Comment: The amplitude always represents the maximum value. Remember that $$|a| = |-n^2 \cdot x| = |-n^2| \cdot |x| = n^2 \cdot |x| \leq n^2 \cdot A.$$ The amplitude of the motion is always less than or equal to $A$.